# Apply base to this CSS pyramid

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have been playing with a demo I found here: http://codepen.io/singhiskng/pen/dqiGj

I am trying to make a 4-sided pyramid.

```
      <div id="pyramid-container">
        <div id="pyramid">
            <div class="face" id="front" ></div>
            <div class="face" id="back" ></div>
            <div class="face" id="left" ></div>
            <div class="face" id="right" ></div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

I have the 4 sides lined up alright, but I would like to have a base underneath them. I attempted to use a pseudo-element, square it off, and rotate it 90 degrees. It isn't appearing however, and I'm uncertain why:

```
#front::after{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-width:0;
    background-color:rgba(147,81,166,0.9);
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateX(90deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r5Xjq/1/

Note: I have applied a 45 degree rotation to `#pyramid` to tilt the pyramid so I can see underneath it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to create the `:before` (or `:after`) element so that its top edge is attached to the bottom edge of some face (such as the `#front`). The bottom face should have size of `50x50`. After attaching like so, you need to rotate the bottom face around the X-axis (as well as the top edge) (using `rotateX`). Because the `#front` face is rotated `30deg`, you need to rotate the bottom face `-120deg` (`-30deg` to make it vertical, then `-90deg` to make it fit right into the bottom flat of the pyramid).

Also note that the container's `transform-style` should be set to `preserve-3d`, so the `transform-style` of the `#front` should also be set to that value. Now is the CSS code details:

```
#front{
    -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;

    -webkit-transform:rotateX(30deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateX(30deg); 
    border-bottom:50px solid rgba(147,81,166,0.9);               
}
#front:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:50px;
    left:-25px;               
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;
    -webkit-transform:rotate3d(1,0,0,-120deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate3d(1,0,0,-120deg);
    background: rgba(180,80,180,0.9);
    border:1px solid rgb(147,81,166,.5);
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/r5Xjq/3/)

Comment: Note that the demo works Ok on webkit-browsers, maybe IE will also render it OK (if we add more `-ms-` prefix for the transforms) **but**  the so-called FireFox 29 renders the triangles too badly (terribly bad, no anti-aliasing, using 3d transform makes no difference), it may be better if we build a larger pyramid.